# Equilateral triangle in Java using for loop

Tags: java, console

I am trying to draw an equilateral triangle of asterisk characters but when a user enters row number *that* row will be drawn as `"x"` and the whole triangle will be `"*"` but I have an error in the spaces.

Here is my code:

```
int number_of_stars = getHeight();
for (int rows=1; rows <= getHeight(); rows++) 
       {
        for (int spaces=1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        if(rows == getRowNum()){
            for (int star=1; star <= rows; star++) 
            {
                System.out.print("x");
                System.out.print(" ");
                }
            System.out.println("");
            rows = getRowNum()+1;
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(" ");

        }
        for (int star=1; star <= rows; star++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.print(" ");
            }
        System.out.println("");
        number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
        }
```

and the output is

```
      * 
     * * 
    * * * 
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
x x x x x x x
```

---

```
 * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

the ninth and tenth rows are incorrect

Comment: This is the right time to fire your debugger and go step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO only change you want for a particular row number is to print `x` rather than `*` and for that you can simply change the character to print. I tried this sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userRowNumber = 5;
        int height = 10;
        int number_of_stars = height;
        String charToPrint;
        for (int rows=1; rows <= height; rows++)
        {
            charToPrint = "*";
            if(rows == userRowNumber){
                charToPrint = "x";
            }
            for (int spaces=1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int star=1; star <= rows; star++)
            {
                System.out.print(charToPrint);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
        }
    }
```

which prints what is expected. For the issue in your code I encourage you to debug and find it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted a simple `if-else` and when you added an extra loop to print the `x`(s) it pushed your alignment off. I think you just wanted,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number_of_stars = getHeight();
    for (int rows = 1; rows <= getHeight(); rows++) {
        for (int spaces = 1; spaces <= number_of_stars; spaces++) {
            System.out.print(" "); // <-- indent(s)
        }
        for (int star = 1; star <= rows; star++) {
            if (rows == getRowNum()) {
                System.out.print("x"); // <-- one row is "x"
            } else {
                System.out.print("*"); // <-- others are "*"
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        number_of_stars = number_of_stars - 1;
    }
}
```